# Get link of an image in react-photo-gallery?

Tags: node.js, database, image, reactjs, url

I'm still a beginner in reactJS (using nodeJS backend) and I have to create a website to manage my collections. I don't know if what I'm going to ask you is feasible, but it probably is.

So I'm using a react component, react-photo-gallery. It's a component where you can use url links and it mixes them together to create a beautiful gallery.

https://github.com/neptunian/react-photo-gallery

I'm using nodeJS to get the information from the database, where I get the urls of all the pictures. For example I have a collection of cards, and an url of the image which represents the collection. **What I want to do is get the link of the picture that I'm clicking on so I can use it in another component.**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Gallery from 'react-photo-gallery';
import Photo from './Photo';


class PhotoGallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      urlImages: []
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    var getUrlImages = 'http://localhost:3004';
    const response = await fetch(getUrlImages+"/getUrlImages");
    const newList = await response.json();
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      ...previousState,
      urlImages: newList,
     }));
  }

  galleryPhotos() {
   if(this.state.urlImages) {
      return this.state.urlImages.map(function(urlimage) {
         return { src: urlimage.urlimage, width: 2, height: 2 }
      })
   }
}

  onClick() {
    alert(this.galleryPhotos().value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Gallery axis={"xy"} photos={this.galleryPhotos()} onClick={this.onClick}/>
    )
  }
}
const photos = [];
export default PhotoGallery;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Basically what I want to do is get the source link of the picture in the onClick function. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `onClick` event.

```
onClick(event) {
  alert(event.target.src)
}
```

The **[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/x3063kpm7z)**

Answer (score 2):

The onClick event of the Gallery component has a number of arguments:

1. the event
2. an object containing the selected index and the original photo object

You can use this in your onClick handler:

```
onClick(e, obj) {
  const src = obj.photo.src
  // do whatever you need with the src (setState, etc)
}
```